# Simultaneous start of multiple 'test suites' (all clones) in Selenium IDE, on as many browsers?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Scenario:
Multiple Firefox browsers with Selenium IDE addon installed, residing in as many VMs in the Host, all containing the same Source i.e. the exact same commands in their respective S-IDE window.

Instead of manually starting each Test Suite, what would you recommend as an elegant solution to (manually) initiate the start of all Test Suites in all browsers at once ?

Here's one idea if anyone's interested, it's descriptively written on purpose:

- The script will check each 30 seconds for an #element# on a personal website of mine to appear by refreshing it.
- If the element is not there, it'll head back to label [NO] after which a Pause [30000] will occur before opening the website again and checking for the desired #element#.
- Whenever I need them to start all at once, within seconds I could modify my website by inserting the required #element#, and save the changes. Additional 30 seconds will be required to make sure all test suites have surely been initiated in the part of the script which is important for me, after which I'll undo the modification on my website.
- So when each script in each browser will detect the #element# this time it'll be instructed to move on to label [YES] after which the important chain of commands will initiate.
- Once (each) script finishes, it'll be instructed to head to that label [NO] mentioned earlier where the process will 'reside' in that loop forever until I again insert the #element# on my personal website if I'm about to repeat the whole procedure.